# Now() or Today() in OData

Tags: datetime, odata, dataexplorer

I have created the StackOverflow OData query [Find unanswered questions by non-noob](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194453/find-unanswered-questions-by-non-noob).

It works fine so far, except that I want to limit the questions to questions asked in the last N days (e.g. 7 days).

I have tried

```
datetime'##Since##T00:00:00'
```

and I have read posts like [OData Date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196273/odata-date-query), but none of them is specifying the date in a relative way to today.

**How can I complete my query to select new questions only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for your problem [over here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193922/top-haskell-questions-for-last-week)
so I added the following lines:

```
DECLARE @today Datetime = getdate()
DECLARE @NrDays int = ##NrDays:int?7##
```

...

```
and datediff(Day,CreationDate,@today) <= @NrDays
```

So this is my solution: [Find unanswered questions by non-noob within last week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194541/find-unanswered-questions-by-non-noob-within-last-week?MinRep=2000&NrDays=7)